# Select 2 issue with on change event not firing on second select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having an issue with select 2 where the second select 2 which is pulling the  from AJAX which is returning the HTML to replace.

The main issue seems to be the second select 2 'select' is not adding the selected atribute for some god forsaken reason... the console.log is not kicking in.

```
function select2_format_flag(state) {
    var originalOption = state.element;
    if (!$(originalOption).data('iso')) return state.text;
    return "<img class='flag' src='<?=$adtrafik_config['uri_assets']?>img/flag/" + $(originalOption).data('iso') + ".gif' /> " + state.text;
}

function select2_format_engine(state) {
    var originalOption = state.element;
    if (!$(originalOption).data('engine')) return state.text;
    return "<img class='engine' src='<?=$adtrafik_config['uri_assets']?>img/img/engine/" + $(originalOption).data('engine') + ".png' /> " + state.text;
}


jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //API Path
    var adtrafik_api = '<?=$adtrafik_config['
    uri_post '].'
    seo / report - regional / api / '?>';
    //Select2
    $('#go').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#d_to').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#d_from').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    //Init. Select2
    $('#d_engine').select2({
        placeholder: "Select Engine...",
        allowClear: true,
        width: 'resolve',
        formatResult: select2_format_engine,
        formatSelection: select2_format_engine
    });
    $("#d_market").select2({
        width: 'resolve',
        formatResult: select2_format_flag,
        formatSelection: select2_format_flag
    });
    $('#go').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var d_from = $('#d_from').val();
        var d_to = $('#d_to').val();
        var data_key_engine = $("#d_engine option:selected").attr('data-engine').toLowerCase();
        var engineid = data_key_engine;
        //var engineid = data_key_market + '-' + data_key_engine;
        <? php
        if (isset($uri_page[2])) { ?>
                window.location.href = '<?php echo $adtrafik_config['
            uri_post '].'
            seo / report - regional / overview / '; ?>' + engineid + '/' + d_from + '/' + d_to + '/'; <? php
        } else { ?>
                window.location.href = '<?php echo $adtrafik_config['
            uri_post '].'
            seo / report - regional / '.$uri_page[2].' / '; ?>' + engineid + '/' + d_from + '/' + d_to + '/'; <? php
        } ?>
    });
    //Add Formatter and AJAX to Market
    $('#d_market').change(function () {
        var id = $('#d_market').val();
        var dataString = 'type=nav&call=d_engine&d_market=' + id;
        var data_key_market = $("#d_market option:selected").attr('data-iso').toLowerCase();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: adtrafik_api,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#d_engine').select2('enable');
                $('#d_engine').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#d_market').change(function () {
        console.log('i changed');
    });
    $('#d_engine').change(function () {
        console.log('i changed too....');
    });
    //END this crap!
});
```

Comment: Ever figured this out? Ran into a similar issue

Comment: @nluigi looked back the repository, seems like it was resolved elsewhere or never fixed it in the end. Coulud be something do with binding events, need to use Select2 to set this event.